# How to pause Timer_Tick after a predefined time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I am working on a web application. In this application i want to pause a timer tick at after 12 minutes. How could i do this ? Or where could i specify that time so that the timer tick get paused?

Comment: You could have a second timer that after 12 minutes stops the first timer.

Comment: How can i stop my timer after a few minutes? @Ben Robinson

Comment: How about having another timer with Duration = 12 minutes. On its tick disable the old one

Comment: @sahilmagoo Use timer.Enabled property set it to false

Comment: How can i calculate12 minutes of time? @Akshay Vats

Comment: @SahilMagoo Make another timer, set its Duration property to 720000 (12 minutes). Attach the tick event. Under this event disable both the timers

Comment: That will add more overhead to application. @ Akshay Vats

Comment: I don't think its much of an overhead. But If you still want to do with one timer. Maybe you can calculate how many times your timer should trigger to reach 12 minutes and then after those many ticks disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state object in the callback to get the timer instance.
Then you can check inside the callback if you want to stop the timer. 
You can simply count the number of ticks and compute the elapsed time in every tick:

```
    ...
    // Start the timer
    // you have to use this constructor if you want to
    // access the timer itself inside callback
    var timer = new Timer(Callback);
    timer.Change(100, period);
}

// Set desired period
private static int period = 100;

// Track elapsed time
private static int elapsed;

private static void Callback(object state)
{
    // update elapsed time
    ellapsed += period;

    // check if ellapsed is greater than 12min
    bool isElapsed = ellapsed >= 12 * 60 * 1000;

    if (!isElapsed) return;

    var timer = state as Timer;

    if ( timer != null)
        timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```